# limit value taxonomy based on previous taxonomy value wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, custom-type

I have created a custom Post Type which Holds up-to Two Taxonomies called "country"- values: "USA", "Russia", "China" , "city" - values: "Chicago", "Moscow", "Beijing",

I want when user in taxonomy "country" choose value "USA" after that in taxonomy "city" show only "chicago". Is it possible? And how can I do this?

is there wordpress plugin that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a custom taxonomy. I don't think that you will find a plugin for that. But here are two solutions on how to do this by youself ;-)

**Solution 1:** 
You could create a get parameter once the user selected a country. For that you could use e.g. a form of type get:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <select name="country" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        // list your options manually or using a loop
        <option value="usa">__( 'USA' )</option>
        .
        .
    </select>
</form>
```

After selecting the country the page should reload and the url will look like this: https://yourdomain.net/?country=usa
You could check this in your custom loop like this

```
if( isset( $_GET['country'] ) ) {
    getCitiesByCountry( $_GET['country'] );
}
else {
    getAllCities();
}
```

And to make the user experience even better you could use ajax in this case. But that's a totally different topic.

**Solution 2:** 
You could load all the cities and just and toggle their visibilities based on the selected country using JavaScript. Here I am assuming that you don't have many cities to choose from ... otherwise it could slow down your site! The upside is that the site wouldn't have to reload, since all the data has already been loaded but only part of it is visible.

Cheers, Dominik